# Why everything in the C# form becomes blurred when running?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, blur

Here is a screenshot to get a clearer understanding to my problem:

[image] .
As you can see that the program is not sharp while the one in the visual studio is sharp and clear. Please help me out as i couldn't find solution to this online.

Comment: What `Control` do you use to display the image? Is it `PictureBox`?

Comment: @Ian yea i used picturebox, but even the words are blurred

Comment: And your `PictureBox` `SizeMode` is `Stretch`, right?

Comment: @Ian it is center image, and it is not just the picture that is blurred it is also the text. http://prntscr.com/9jrln2 , hope u can see the differences

Comment: Ah, I can see that... okay... this is even stranger. I personally never encounter such case. =( Will see if I could be of any help.

Comment: @Ian thanks for helping, didnt know this is a rare case.

Comment: Yeah, at least I cannot reproduce the error in my winform app. =( But maybe there are plenty others who understand the issue here..

Comment: What is the Windows verstion? Which .Net are you using? What dpi is on your system?

Comment: @AlexButenko i am using Windows 8.1, visual studio 2015. Not sure how to check DPI thou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to re-sizing of your windows form. So more you enlarge the window the images becomes blurred. you can embed this resource in your project and correct few properties for that image.

Comment: How do i make sure it is the same size as the one in the visual studio, i have not touched on re-sizing the windows form yet so everything is in default. Any way to make the windows form run and look the same as the one i'm editing ?